# Función para que el script jale los campos de la segunda hoja de cálculo

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Estoy programando una notificación por correo cada vez que se llena un formulario de Google.

Hasta ahora todo bien con la primera hoja, ya que se trabaja por evento puedo jalar la información directamente de la columna.

Formulario
[image: FORMULARIO PRINCIPAL]

Base de datos
[image: BASE DE DATOS EN HOJA DE CALCULO]

Correo recibido
[image: CORREO RECIBIDO]

Como pueden ver hay una serie de datos que aparecen como "undefinied"

Estos datos los encuentro en la segunda hoja de calculo ya que los tengo con formulas para hacer los cálculos correspondientes

segunda hoja de cálculo
[image]

Tengo un código que me jala la información directamente para generar el correo

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var usuarioEmail = 'psi.danielhdez@gmail.com';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var msg = "<p>Buen día solicito tu apoyo con el siguiente proceso:</p>"+ "<br>"+

    "Fecha Nacimiento:   <b>" +e.values[1]+ "</b><br>"+
    "Puesto:    <b>" +e.values[2]+ "</b><br>"+
    "Salario:   <b>" +e.values[3]+ "</b><br>"+

    "Salario catorcenal:" +e.values[24]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal:" +e.values[25]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal integrado:" +e.values[31]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario fiscal catorcenal:" +e.values[28]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario efectivo catorcenal :" +e.values[50]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario efectivo:" +e.values[32]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario TOTAL:" +e.values[33]+ "<br>"+


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: usuarioEmail,
    subject: "solicitud de alta de empleado",
    htmlBody: msg
  }
  );

}
```

Claramente los otros datos no están bien referenciados `(SALARIO CATORCENAL : SALARIO DIARIO TOTAL)`, pero no logro encontrar la función correcta para que el script jale los campos de la segunda hoja de cálculo `Salarios`.
la pregunta es ¿Cómo hago tal cosa?

---

Gracias por tus observaciones soy nuevo en esto  del google script.
Pongo aqui el codigo.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var usuarioEmail = 'psi.danielhdez@gmail.com';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var msg = "<p>Buen día solicito tu apoyo con el siguiente proceso:</p>"+ "<br>"+

    "Fecha Nacimiento:   <b>" +e.values[1]+ "</b><br>"+
    "Puesto:    <b>" +e.values[2]+ "</b><br>"+
    "Salario:   <b>" +e.values[3]+ "</b><br>"+

    "Salario catorcenal:" +e.values[24]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal:" +e.values[25]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal integrado:" +e.values[31]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario fiscal catorcenal:" +e.values[28]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario efectivo catorcenal :" +e.values[50]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario efectivo:" +e.values[32]+ "<br>"+
    "Salario diario TOTAL:" +e.values[33]+ "<br>"+


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: usuarioEmail,
    subject: "solicitud de alta de empleado",
    htmlBody: msg
  }
  );

}
```

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, te sugiero, trates de publicar el código en texto así será más fácil reproducir el `bug`. No obstante al ver la documentación sobre la API: [Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) en `MailApp.sendEmail({... body:... })` y en el screenshot que has mostrado dice `htmlBody:`. Por otro lado aunque de acuerdo a la [API de Googel Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) también es soportado `java` entre otros, en este caso el lenguaje posteado es `JS` no `java`.

Answer (score 1):

El formulario mostrado en la imagen contiene 3 preguntas así que la propiedad values del objeto evento contendrá sólo cuatro elementos, el primero correspondiente a la marca temporal y los otros tres a cada una de las preguntas. Por otro lados los índices en objetos Array son base 0.

En otras palabras, al usar los índices 23, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33 y 50 devuelven `undefined` porque esos elementos no existen en `e.values`.

Para tomar una valor de una hoja de cálculo de Google se debe tomar primero el rango donde se encuentre el valor en cuestión, para lo cual existen diversos métodos, tales como el conjunto de métodos `getRange(...)`, `getDataRange()`, `getActiveRange()`, entre otros.

Una vez que has tomado el rango, puedes usar `getValue()`, `getValues()`, `getDisplayValue()`, ó `getDisplayValues()` para tomar el valor o valores ya sea una celda o varias celdas las que abarca el rango tomado.

Answer (score 0):

Hice un test no con una form pero en teoria daria lo mismo lo importante es lo que esta dentro de la funcion. Como bien Ruben indicaba hay que obtener los valores de las celdas especificamente con metodos especificos. En este caso se obtiene el valor numerico de la ultima celda con datos, esta estara tomando el valor de la ultima no importando si hay celdas vacias entre las anteriores y la ultima celda asi que es importante que no se agrege informacion abajo de la ultima linea llena por el formulario.

Aca esta el codigo que realize para esta prueba, solamente tendria que testearlo con el formulario a la hora de submitir la respuesta.

```
function formSubmitReply() {
   var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = sp.getSheets()[1];
  var acs = sp.setActiveSheet(sh);
  var lt = sh.getLastRow();
  var usuarioEmail = "CorreoElectronico";
  var A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K;

  A = acs.getRange("A:A" + lt).getValue();
  B = acs.getRange("B:B" + lt).getValue();
  C = acs.getRange("C:C" + lt).getValue();
  D = acs.getRange("D:D" + lt).getValue();
  E = acs.getRange("E:E" + lt).getValue();
  F = acs.getRange("F:F" + lt).getValue();
  G = acs.getRange("G:G" + lt).getValue();
  H = acs.getRange("H:H" + lt).getValue();
  I = acs.getRange("I:I" + lt).getValue();
  J = acs.getRange("J:J" + lt).getValue();
  K = acs.getRange("K:K" + lt).getValue();

    var msg = "<p>Buen día solicito tu apoyo con el siguiente proceso:</p>"+ "<br>"+

    "Fecha Nacimiento:   <b>" + A + "</b><br>"+
    "Puesto:    <b> " + B + "</b><br>"+
    "Salario:   <b> " + C + "</b><br>"+
    "Salario catorcenal: " + D + "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal: " + E + "<br>"+
    "Salario diario fiscal integrado: " + F + "<br>"+
    "Salario fiscal catorcenal: " + G + "<br>"+
    "Salario efectivo catorcenal: " + H + "<br>"+
    "Salario diario efectivo:" + I + "<br>"+
    "Salario diario TOTAL: " + J + "<br>"+
      "Cuenta de Banco: " + K;

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: usuarioEmail,
    subject: "solicitud de alta de empleado",
    htmlBody: msg
  }
  ); 

}
```

Solamente reemplaze el correo electronico y recuerde que la funcion fue testeada manualmente solo sustituyala por la funcion actual que tiene o realice pruebas para asegurarse de que funcione bien con su actual formulario.

Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos.